# What ciphers/digests are supported by AF_ALG?

Tags: openssl

Is there a command that determines the complete list of ciphers and digests supported by af_alg for any given version of openssl. 
Note that I am using openssl 1.1.1

Comment: It's up to the kernel what ciphers are supported by af_alg.

Comment: Hi @Sony and welcome to Information Security! You may improve your question by providing more context, and maybe a link to the af_alg spec. Also consider applying some relevant tags.